# What's the differences between 'python svn' and 'python pysvn'?

Tags: python, pysvn

I need to use svn or pysvn of python to get svn repository log and info etc, but I don't know what's the differences between these two modules and how to choose a more appropriate module. Is there any advice?

Answer (score 1):

`pip install svn` is called `PySvn` [on their github](https://github.com/dsoprea/PySvn) but `svn` [on PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/svn/). It looks like it has open tickets and fairly recent version update within the last 6 months.

There is an older `PySVN` which can be [found on SourceForge](https://pysvn.sourceforge.io/) but it does not seem to be currently updated or have active development going on.

You should use the version on PyPi via pip install considering it seems to be a more actively developed module.

Comment: PySVN on SourceForge is actively maintained -- last change 2 days ago, while PYSVN on GitHub hasn't been updated in over 2 years now.

Answer (score 1):

pysvn offeres a pythonic object oriented interface to svn.

I actively maintain pysvn and use. The slow rate of change is a sign of the maturity of the software.

There are prebuilt kits for windows and macOS. linux systems package it for example debian and fedora.

pysvn is not installed from PyPI becuase of that would require the user to install compilers and developer libraries.

Read more on https://pysvn.sourceforge.io/